# How do I define a specific area within a JqueryUI draggable that can "touch" a JqueryUI droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have on my page a draggable div, and then a big table of droppable td's.  I want the droppable td's to be highlighted that "touch" only a certain portion of the draggable div.

hopefully this fiddle makes it clearer:  https://jsfiddle.net/mattlokk/e2nyxqhv/10/

(code in the fiddle to satisfy posting requirements:)

Html

```
<table id='tblDropArea'>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<div id='divDraggable' style='width: 80px; height: 160px; background-color: #ff0; border: 1px solid #ccc;'>
</div>
```

Css

```
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#tblDropArea{
    border-collapse: collapse;  
}
#tblDropArea tr td {
  width: 85px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  height: 45px;  
}
.drop-hover{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

JS

```
$("#divDraggable").draggable({
  appendTo: 'body',
  helper: 'clone',
    start: function(event, ui){
    $(this).hide();
    $(ui.helper).append("<div class='divEventDropPortion' style='position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 20px; width: 0px; height: calc(100% - 40px); border: 1px solid #000;' ></div>")
  },
  stop: function () { $(this).show(); }
});

$("#tblDropArea tr td").droppable({
    accept: ".divEventDropPortion",
  hoverClass: "drop-hover",
  tolerance: "touch",
  drop: function (event, ui) {
  }
});
```

when you pick up the yellow div, a black vertical line appears in the middle of it.  I only want the droppable td's that touch that line to be highlighted.

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924907/jquery-ui-set-up-my-own-tolerance/34979803#34979803

Comment: yikes.  that looks promising, but also like it's a lot more complicated than I had hoped.